# resttemplate.exchange throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, resttemplate

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(url,entity, String.class);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

Throws null pointer exception when trying to create an object.

I checked entity and url, it is getting printed in Logger message. But at this line it throws null pointer exception, but the object is still getting created..

If the object is getting created how can this throw null pointer exception..

I am using kubernetes, when i check command line in kubernetes it says object got created..but in logs it shows null pointer exception

Comment: Can you post the stackTrace?

Comment: @Luanmalaguti i tried commenting resttemplate.postforentity, after commenting that line, in logs--> object is getting created successfully..resttemplate.postforentity and resttemplate.exchange cant be used parallelly?

Comment: @JavaLearner1 Please post the exception. Another thing: Do you use both of the requests? `restTemplate.postForEntity(url,entity, String.class);` already returns you an `ResponseEntity<String> response`. See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForEntity-java.net.URI-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-)

Comment: I mean, can you post the NullPointer exception log that you are receiving @JavaLearner1

Comment: @kamwo yeah, that was my mistake..i was using both these requests, so it was trying to create objects 2 times..that was throwing the error..

Comment: @Luanmalaguti Luan error got resolved, thank you :)

Comment: @JavaLearner1 okay, than I will write an answer, which you can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem to be that you are executing the request **two times**.

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

Both `postForEntity` and `exchange` are sending a post request to your `url`. `postForEntity` can be seen as a specific case for the `exchange` method. See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForEntity-java.net.URI-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-)

Please use only one of them, for example:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was with it for 2 days. Below was my stacktrace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.put(Charset.java:538)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.access$200(Charset.java:271)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset$3.run(Charset.java:584)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset$3.run(Charset.java:573)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets(Charset.java:572)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.getAcceptedCharsets(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:41)
```

The root cause was in the availableCharsets() static method in Charset class. One of the charset provider was returning a null iterator and the below piece of code i.hasNext() was throwing a null pointer exception.

```
private static void put(Iterator<Charset> i, Map<String,Charset> m) {
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Charset cs = i.next();
            if (!m.containsKey(cs.name()))
                m.put(cs.name(), cs);
        }
    }
```

If you backtrace the stacktrace call, the StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal() method checks the writeAcceptCharset boolean and then calls the getAcceptedCharsets() from where Charset static method is called. To avoid this call, add the below lines.

```
StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter=new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
stringHttpMessageConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
responseEntity=restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl.toString(), HttpMethod.GET,request, <your_class>.class);
```